# How to have separate instance of ASP.NET dataset for each API call?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dataset

I have a project that is already developed using dataset in Visual Studio, and I want to use the same datasets for CRUD transactions for my newly developed web app.

When two users try to add a new record exactly at the same time, it happens that the record is inserted into another database. For instance instead of saving that record in table x of DB1, it is saved in table x of db2.

Here is the code for instantiating the dataset:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpOptions]
[System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
[System.Web.Http.Route("api/PayAndReceive/AddForm")]

public string AddForm([FromBody] FormList MdlObject)
{
   clsConnectionString clnn = new clsConnectionString(MdlObject.BaseParams[0].ToString().Trim(), MdlObject.BaseParams[1].ToString());
   Z.DAL.DataSetAlls.D1DataTable datatable1 = new Zeus.DAL.DataSetAlls.D1DataTable();
   Z.DAL.DataSetAllsTableAdapters.D1TableAdapter adapter1 = new Z.DAL.DataSetAllsTableAdapters.D1TableAdapter();
```

Here is the class:

```
public class clsConnectionString
{
    public string ConnectionStringIS = "";
    private void SetConnectionString(string CorporationID, string FisCalYear)
    {

        string ServerName = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ServerName"].ToString();
        string ISDbName = "DB" + "" + CorporationID + "" + FisCalYear;
        ConnectionStringIS = "Data Source=" + "" + ServerName + ";" + "Initial Catalog =" + "" + ISDbName + ";" + "Integrated Security = True" + ";";
        Z.DAL.SetConnectionString cls = new Z.DAL.SetConnectionString();
        cls.setISDBConnectionString = 
    }
}
```

There are other places in the code that same table and adapter is created and I have added setting connection string before all of them, in order to make sure they are using correct database for table creation.

Is it a correct way of creating a datatable in an api?

Is it ok to have ConnectionStringIS as a public variable or it may make a problem when it is used in an api?

Does dataTable1 and Adapter1 will be connected to new db when another api call happens and that causes the issue?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Ok, looking at above, you have cls.setISDBConnectionString =. So the question is where is this class instance created? It can't be static. if you always createing a new instance of the above class, or using above to get the connection string, then you are fine. But, cls.setISDBConnectionString = looks to be global here (and can't be static). My best guess is you may well have to put the connection in session(), but we have to see/know where this "cls" class instance is being created. Same goes for Z.DAL?? Where in above is a instance of that class being created? (and again, it can't be static)

Comment: So, in both of these cases (z, and cls), they can't be static class. You have to ensure that each use of the data creates a instance of these 2 classes, or you perhaps save/put them into session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

any chance you using a static class for this?

You can't make/create/set/have/use a static class for persisting this data set.

You can certainly have a whole bunch of static helper routines, and a libary of code as static and that is fine.

but, you certainly don't want to have nor use a static class for connections, or the datasets.

So, you posted this:

```
Z.DAL.DataSetAlls.D1DataTable datatable = new 
   Zeus.DAL.DataSetAlls.D1DataTable();

 Z.DAL.DataSetAllsTableAdapters.D1TableAdapter adapter = new 
   Z.DAL.DataSetAllsTableAdapters.D1TableAdapter();
```

The above looks fine, as LONG as you not attempting to persit the dataset in a static class. Static classes are shared among all users of the web site.

So, say in a page on load, if the above code is say in that page class, then you are fine.

However, if the above code is global - in some static class, then you can't do that, since static class(s) if global persisted are shared amoung all users.

So, say I want to fill a grid view? (and I not using the pre Entitfy Framework dataset designer, or the newer EF data designer)?

Then I am free to do this:

Say, I want to load a gridview, then this is fine:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM People ORDER BY Family_ID, FamilyType DESC";
        SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL);
        GridView1.DataSource = General.MyRstP(cmdSQL);
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

so, in above, note how I don't crete a "instance" of class General. "Genreal" is my shared libary code - all kinds of helper routines in that static class.

So, MyRstP is this:

```
    public static DataTable MyRstP(SqlCommand cmdSQL)
    {
        DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (cmdSQL)
            {
                cmdSQL.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            }
        }
        return rstData;
    }
```

Again, note how that routine creates a connection object. But, as such, it not global to the class "general", and thus it is multi-user safe.

So, your posted code looks fine, but only if that posted code is not part of a static class that attempts to persist the values global to that class.

And it not all that clear why you have more then one connection to the database, and that such connections are "different" for each user. That's not a normal approach here, and especially when using dataset designer, or the newer Entity Frameworks. They REALLY do not work if you design assuming is to have multiple connections for that EF or dataset designer active at the same time.

In other words?

You really can't on the fly change the active connection for the dataset designer, or the EF designer since such connections are going to be persisted, and you can't have multiple active connections at the same time.

as a FYI:

The term and use of "dataset" in above has ZERO ZERO to do with the type object called datatable, or dataset (which is a collection of tables).

While it is VERY but VERY rare to have multiple active connections for the SAME tables in a given applcation? You can certainly have multiple database connections active, but not for a single given EF and not for the DS designer.

You can get away with such a less than ideal design for desktop applications, since each desktop has their own copy of running code. On a web site, you have ONE copy of the code, and all logged on users share that code. A new instance of running code is not created for each new user who logs into the site.

So any public vars to a static class are in fact shared among all users. But, of course as my above General class example shows, each routine is free to create instances of objects - even connection objects. but, you certainly cannot have public vars global to the static class, since as noted, you NOT creating an instance of that class when it is used by all logged on users.

So all functions (methods) of the class are fine for that static class, but you can't adopt nor use public vars in that class, since you never creating a instance of the class.

It not clear if you are creating a connection object or those datasets inside of a static class. If you are then simply don't make that class static, and thus in your code you can simple create a instance of that class, including the public connection object and even the public datasets in that class. But, that class can't be static.

So, if you need multiple different connections? then don't use a static class to hold that connection and datasets information, and you should be fine.

Edit
In your sample code you don't show how and where you are setting the connection- we need to see that code.